# promise then() chaining - order is affected by use of bound function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm new to node & js, and am getting some behavior I don't understand using Node 4.3.2 and the latest AWS module which has added support for promises (via the promise() function)...

```
class X {
...
load() {
    dynamodb.getItem( params ).promise()
      .then( log( 'then1') )
      .then( 
        this.onThen.bind(this)
       ).then( log('then3') )
      .catch( (err) => { error( err ); } ); 
    ...
}

onThen(data) {
    log( 'then2' );   // why does this get executed last??
}
...
```

I read about promise chaining vs. branching and sorted that out, so now I'm chaining and I expect the following code to execute the 'then' blocks such that I get 'then1, then2, then3', but instead 'then2' comes last.

This tells me that something in the calling of the bound function is happening asynchronously.  So I looked up [bound functions on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) and I don't see any suggestion that binding makes the function async.

So, please tell me why 'then2' is output after 'then3', and what I could be doing such that my desire to have 'this' set on my onThen member function doesn't impact the order in which my 'then' functions get executed.

Comment: then()s are executed in the order they are called. you call the "then3" part before load() even returns... it has nothing to do with `.bind()`, it's just order of operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this would be because the log statements are not functions, they're function calls, so they're called to retrieve the function that will eventually be called, which immediately logs to the console. they're not called after the promise, try binding all three logs into functions, I'll bet you will see what you expect

Answer (score 0):

```
.then( log( 'then1') )
```

should be

```
.then(function () { log( 'then1' ) } )
```

Otherwise you are calling `log` and passing *the result* to `then`.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call then you are adding a function or value to the stack.

When you call .then( log('then1') ) you're not actually adding that function to the stack, instead you're immediately calling log('then1') and then adding the return value of that to the stack.

Instead, that should be like:

```
.then(function() { log('then1') })
```

That will actually add that anonymous function to the stack and then when it is called, you should see 'then1' show up in your logs.

When you later, in the second "then" call:

```
this.onThen.bind(this)
```

what you're doing is saying when the "onThen" function is called, the value referred to as "this" inside of that function definition should be the value of "this" right now at the time of binding (which would be the promise). I doubt this is what you meant to do.

I don't actually see you calling the onThen function, so I'd be surprised if "then2" ever makes it into your log.